# ¿Cómo puedo descargar una imagen con requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, python-requests

Intento descargar una imagen en una pagina web con python pero si el codigo no devuelve ningiuna error, no descarga la imagen tampoco:

```
import requests
import time
import shutil 

url = "https://i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412020030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88"

r = requests.get(url)
with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutil.copyfileobj` espera también un objeto file-like como datos de orígen, debes pasar el argumento `stream` con valor `True` a `requests.get`:

```
import requests
import shutil


url = "https://i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412020030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88"

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```